# iPhone-X - How to force user to swipe twice home indicator to go home-screen

Tags: ios, ios11, iphone-x

I'm using the code below to hide the home indicator on iPhone X, which is working fine in the emulator.

```
-(BOOL)prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden
{
    return YES;
}
```

But even though it's hidden, I am still able to swipe up from the bottom and my game goes to the home screen.

I have seen a few games where the user has to swipe up once to bring up the home indicator and swipe up again to go to the home screen.

So, how can I force the user to swipe the home indicator twice to go to the home screen in iOS 11 with Objective-C?

This behavior is required for full-screen games.

Answer (score 15):

I [had the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52875222/473409).

`PrefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden` must return NO but also `PreferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures` must be overridden and return `UIRectEdgeBottom`.

### Swift 4.2

```
override var prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden: Bool {
  return false
}

override var preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures: UIRectEdge {
  return UIRectEdge.bottom
}
```

Comment: It is worth noting you can return .all if you want to restrict all gestures, like swiping down from top for Command Center.

Answer (score 6):

Adding the following to the ViewController did the trick for me:

```
- (UIRectEdge)preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures
{
    return UIRectEdgeBottom;
}
```

This made the Home Indicator more transparent and inactivated so that it requires an extra swipe in order to leave the game.

You can also use `UIRectEdgeAll` instead of `UIRectEdgeBottom` to defer the system gestures on all edges of the screen.

Comment: Yea forgot that one too. Though if the prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden returns 'yes' it still doesn't behave the right way, I am suprised it would let you just to defer without registering to received the deferred notification

Answer (score 4):

It is a choice between hidden and deferred but NOT both

```
-(BOOL)prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden
{
    // YES for hidden (but swipe activated)
    // NO for deferred (app gets priority gesture notification)
    return NO;  
}
```

register the gesture in viewDidLoad

```
UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer *sePanGesture = [[UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGesture:)];
sePanGesture.edges = UIRectEdgeAll; 
// or just set the bottom if you prefer, top-right seems to behave well by default
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:sePanGesture];
```

and define the handleGesture, no need to do anything there for this to work

```
- (void)handleGesture:(UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    // to get location where the first touch occurred from docs
    // CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:[recognizer.view superview]]; 

    NSLog(@"gestured");
}
```

should be it

Comment: "but not both" needs to be emphasized

Answer (score 0):

This works for me :

```c
-(bool) prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden {

return NO;

}
```