# Requiring two swipes to enable home gesture functionality

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I'm building a game for the new iPhone X series phones and I have noticed that some games on the App Store require that the user swipe up once to enable the home swipe functionality and then a second swipe up will allow the user to go the to the home screen.

With my game I don’t have this function yet and I was wondering how I can add this to my game.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iPhone X hide home indicator on view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46692121/iphone-x-hide-home-indicator-on-view-controller)

Comment: so it almost helped but the answer that really worked was this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47347403/iphone-x-how-to-force-user-to-swipe-twice-home-indicator-to-go-home-screen. Check out the answer for Swift 4.2

But I only found it cause of the link you gave me, so thanks for that